# Spring boot and hibernate application deployed on TOMEE server

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, apache-tomee

Hi i have an spring boot application with Hibernate as ORM to fetch data from sybase database.

I have a very basic setup and its working fine with embedded server.
I used this following site to generate a war and deploy it to local tomcat server successfully.
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/.

I was able to deploy the application onto TOMEE server by overriding TOMEE persistance setting
CATALINA_OPTS=-javax.persistence.provider=org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
abd placing required hibernate jars in TOMEE/lib.

Problem is when i try to access data, the request in the DAO calls sessionfactory.getcurrentsession() i am receiving following error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized 
Session for current thread    
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
```

I am using Spring Boot : 1.3.0
TOMEE 1.7.4

Please dont judge me on my coding as this is just a snippet and my app configurations

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/netgloo_blog
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

MY Main Application

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootWebApplication extends 
SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
    return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
}

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

   @Autowired
   UserService service

@RequestMapping("/authenticate")
public String authenticate(httpServletRequest req, HtttpServletResponse res) 
{
    return service.authenticate(req.getParameter("userId"));
}

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Autowired
UserManager userManager

@override
public String authenticate(String userId) 
{
    return userManager.authenticate(userId);
}
```

}

Additional Manager layer

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager{

@Autowired
UserDao userDao

@override
public String authenticate(String userId) 
{
    User user = userDao.CheckUserIsPresentInDB(userId);
    if(user !=  null){
    return "success";
    }
}

}
```

DAO layer

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory

 @override
public User authenticate(String userId) 
{
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria;
   ----

}

}
```

Application runs fine on my local Tomcat 7 server 
but getting errror to get transaction on TOMEE server.

Do i have need to make any changes to the code or to TOMEE server ?
Please help

Comment: I have solved the issue by removing the bean
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

and autowirinng Persistance context as entity manager 
i then unpacked the underlying sessionFactory from entityManager using entityManager.unWrap()

Answer (score 0):

If using JTA implicitly, you can configure the transaction manager access either through a lookup or factory access (OpenEJB.getTransactionManager()).